# Powershell converts & into &amp when update an XML inner text

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update an xml inner text with this string

```
$command = "All jobs are done &gt jobsdone.txt"
```

But After save it to an XML,the inner text becomes `"All jobs are done &ampgt jobsdone.txt"`.

I don't know how to write `&` in xml inner text.

Comment: Please show us the full code you use to set the inner text to `$command`

Comment: Have you tried `$command="All jobs are done > jobsdone.txt"`?

Comment: Share your code @Ramkumar

Answer (score 0):

Your **&gt** missing a terminating semi-colon.